Ubuntu is not starting even it's booted
I booted Ubuntu 23.10 on my Lenovo X230. Before I had Linux Mint and it worked perfectly. So I wanted to try out Ubuntu.
After I booted Ubuntu my laptop always goes to the booting settings without starting Ubuntu. And when I want to reinstall Ubuntu it also gives me the option "Install Ubuntu alongside Ubuntu 23.10". So that's very strange.
Does someone have a solution for that?

always goes to the booting settings -- you mean bios/uefi settings or something else?

You may just have to make ubuntu the default boot option in uefi settings without reinstalling.

@ArchismanPanigrahi Yea, meant the Settings when you press F12 (where you use the boot system). Sorry, I'm new into Linux

Try changing the boot order in uefi settings

Does this answer your question? How to change boot priority?

Watch the lights of your internet connector and harddisk; probably the system is started but you have nothing on your screen. Can be becouse the screen configuration changed after first install.
